# Error message whenever I try to commit my changes to GitHub

Tags: git, github, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-commit

Whenever I try to commit my changes I get an error message.

I use git version 2.30.2. This is the error

```
error: unsupported value for gpg.format: ssh

fatal: bad config variable 'gpg.format' in file '/home/greenydev/.gitconfig' at line 9
```

This is what my .gitconfig looks like when I cat. Is there also an issue with it?

```
[user]

        email = <my email>

        name = <my name>

        signing key = /home/<user>/.ssh/id_...

[credentia]

        helper = store --file /home/<user>/.my-credentials

[gpg]

        format = ssh
```

I tried this out today and was expecting my. Changes to be committed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+bad+config+variable+%22gpg.format%22

Comment: Martin Thoma: "*SSH signing is only available with `git>=2.34`*"

Comment: I deleted the last line ```format = ssh```

Comment: The similar question my post was associated with didn't get answered and was deleted. I realized that I couldn't ask a question as a comment and decided to re ask the question on here. I already got the answer to my question and wrote it here. Kindly reopen the question so that people with similar problems can find a solution or at least get some direction. Thank you.

Comment: The question is not similar, it's an exact duplicate. The answer is there, at the duplicate question. If you have a different answer you also can put it there, no need to reopen this question.